# IF NOT EXISTS error

Tags: postgresql

I have to check the existence of the test schema before creating it.
but my code don't work !! do you have any idea?

```
BEGIN 

IF NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT schema_name
      FROM information_schema.schemata
      WHERE schema_name = 'TEST'
  )
THEN
    CREATE SCHEMA "TEST";

END IF;
```

END

my error message:
ERROR: syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 3: IF NOT EXISTS (

Comment: You need to wrap this in a `do` block: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html  But it would be much easier to simply use `create schema test if not exists`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createschema.html

Comment: Thank you it's work, but i have another problem. how can i do to for multiple instructions in blocks THEN END if like BEGIN 

    IF NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT schema_name
          FROM information_schema.schemata
          WHERE schema_name = 'TEST'
      )
    THEN
        CREATE SCHEMA "TEST";
 ALTER SCHEMA "Test" OWNER TO Test_USER;
 SET search_path = "TEST", pg_catalog;
 SET default_tablespace = '';
 SET default_with_oids = false;

    END IF;

END

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS test;
```

, or:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS test AUTHORIZATION the_user;
```

(the NOT EXISTS clause for CREATE SCHEMA was introduced somewhere in postgres-9.x, IIRC)

Comment: `IF NOT EXISTS` as used here for creating schemas is available at 9.3 , FYI.